# How do I change the <body> background image matching same image of my jQuery carousel?

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

This is out of my skills so please if somebody have an idea or logic to do the trick it will save my life. I've been trying to use a simple jQuery carousel and all I need is change the background image of my site according to the image inside my carousel. It's been a challenge for me.

Comment: can you please post some of your code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this bit of JavaScript:

```
var changeBodyBackground = function() {
    var theImageUrl = $('#IdOfYourCarouselDiv img').attr('src');
    $('body').css({backgroundImage : 'url(' + theImageUrl + ')'});
};
```

You will have to change `'#IdOfYourCarouselDiv img'` to select the div containing the `<img>` you want to use for the background.

You also want to make sure you add a call to `changeBodyBackground();` whenever the image changes in the carousel.

Comment: I got confess! My skills in flash made my decision then I decided use the new functions and classes of AS3 like "flash.external.ExternalInterface", to call my javascript function and in less than 30min the job was done. So, here is the path: